# OpenSSL threads and Helgrind

Tags: multithreading, openssl, valgrind

I am implementing a multi-threaded application which makes extensive use of OpenSSL crypto library.

I have followed the guidelines in several posts here ([Tutorial on Using OpenSSL with pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417706/openssl-and-multi-threads), [OpenSSL and multi-threads](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html)), websites (eg [libcurl opensslthreadlock.c](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html)) and mainly the sample code in the *crypto/threads/mttest.c* program contained within OpenSSL source code. The examples therein referenced mostly deal with OpenSSL's static lock callback functions. But, also according to OpenSSL documentation on the matter ([OpenSSL: threads(3)](http://www.amazon.es/Definitive-Guide-Network-Programming-Experts/dp/1590593227)) and on [The Definitive Guide to Linux Network Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919420/tutorial-on-using-openssl-with-pthreads)  (pages 255-259), it may sometimes be necessary to define some functions for dynamic lock management.

Hence, I have implemented initialization and cleanup functions that set both types of lock management functions (static and dynamic). These functions are as follows:

```
static unsigned long _thread_id_function(void) {
  return ((unsigned long) pthread_self());
}

static void _locking_function(int mode, int id, const char *file, int line) {
  if(mode & CRYPTO_LOCK) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_buffer[id]);
  } else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_buffer[id]);
  }
}

static struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value* _dyn_create_func(const char *file, int line) {
  struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *value;
  value = (struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *) malloc(sizeof(struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value));
  pthread_mutex_init(&value->mutex,NULL);
  return value;
}

static void _dyn_destroy_func(struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l, 
  const char *file, int line) {
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&l->mutex);
  free(l);
  return;
}

static void _dyn_lock_func(int mode, struct CRYPTO_dynlock_value *l,
  const char *file, int line) {
  if(mode & CRYPTO_LOCK) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&l->mutex);
  } else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&l->mutex);
  }
}

static int _static_init() {

  int i;

  mutex_buffer = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks()*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

  for(i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_buffer[i], NULL);
  }

  CRYPTO_set_id_callback(_thread_id_function);
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(_locking_function);

  return 0;

}

static int _static_cleanup() {

  int i;

  CRYPTO_set_id_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);

  for(i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_buffer[i]);
  }

  free(mutex_buffer); mutex_buffer = NULL;
  return 0;
}

static int _dyn_init() {
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(_dyn_create_func);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(_dyn_lock_func);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(_dyn_destroy_func);
  return 0;
}

static int _dyn_cleanup() {
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback(NULL);
  CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback(NULL);
  return 0;
}

int cryptothread_init() {
  _static_init();
  _dyn_init();
  return 0;
}

int cryptothread_cleanup() {
  _static_cleanup();
  _dyn_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

From my main program, I call the *cryptothread_init* function to initialize the callbacks.
However, if I run Valgrind's Helgrind tool, several race conditions occur, e.g.:

> ==18797== Possible data race during write of size 4 at 0x75D2F28 by thread #3
>
> ==18797== Locks held: none
>
> ==18797==    at 0x7276DCA: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72F6290: EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72FD57B: EVP_SignFinal (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x407007: sign_data (main.c:919)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x4C2B5AD: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x5CACB4F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x6F4EA7C: clone (clone.S:112)
>
> ==18797==
>
> ==18797== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #4
>
> ==18797== Locks held: none
>
> ==18797==    at 0x7276DCA: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72B0086: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72B05AC: bn_expand2 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72B08C9: BN_set_word (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72B1317: BN_CTX_get (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72AD68A: BN_div (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72D1841: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==    by 0x72D2B9A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
>
> ==18797==

Still, the lock callbacks do not throw any error/warning message. Any hint about what may I be missing?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well... did you ever determine how to configure OpenSSL and valgrind to resolve or mask these reports?